# Why is Pyro Pete the Invincible not dropping Seraph Crystals?

Tags: borderlands-2

I finished the Torgue DLC on playthrough 2, and decided to kill Pyro Pete the Invincible to get myself some Seraph Crystals. I had seen many videos on Youtube showing him dropping a mess of them, and he seemed the easiest of the Seriph Invincibles to farm. I did the mission for Moxxi to spawn him the first time, killed him, turned in the quest, and returned to Pete's Bar.

I took the elevator down, spent the 8 eridium, and he did not hop down. The board was dark, and my 8 eridium was gone, but no Pete. I saved and quit, retried, and this time he did spawn.  I killed him, and he dropped no legendaries, no crystals, and only 4 eridium.

Frustrated, I saved and quit, and tried again; he took my 8 eridium, and again failed to jump down. Of the next 20 attempts he failed to jump down 3 times, beat me 2 times, and the other 15 (when I beat him) he dropped no legendaries and no Seraph Crystals.

I was using my lv 61 Soldier that has completed the main storyline for ultimate vault hunter mode (playthrough 3) so Pete is not too hard to kill, but there is no point if he drops nothing.

Is Pete's refusal to drop Seraph Crystals due to my being 9 levels higher than him? Is it because I have not completed Scarlette's DLC yet? Do I have to beat Hyperious once first? If I have to beat Hyperious, can i di it in Normal Mode (Playthrough 1), or do I have to beat him in Playthrough 2?

What (if anything) can I do to resolve this, and start getting some Seraph Crystals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seraphs used to drop Seraph Crystals in Playthrough 2 when that was the last playthrough available; with the addition of the Ultimate Vault Hunter pack, there is a new last playthrough (#3), so they only drop the crystals in that playthrough.

Comment: Wow really? Do they at least drop more? Because they were already BS bosses with horrible drop rates...

Comment: The drop rate did not change, though many Seraph items are easier to get now, having been removed from the vendors, and instead made into not-terribly-rare drops from the Seraphs themselves.

Comment: Adding to this, Seraph crystals can also be obtained through Tiny Tina's DLC (Assault on Dragon Keep) if you spend Eridium on the special slot machines and get lucky enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me on solo. But every time I go online and people are going to pyro pete I see that he drops serriph crystal (Probaly like 5-10) So I think you might just have to play online to get legendary guns and serriph crystals

Answer (score 0):

Playing with another person is the best way to get seraph crystals as he will not drop in solo captain scarletts dlc must complete as far as I know

Answer (score -1):

Every raid boss drops seraph crystals In ultimate even in solo, and also every raid boss has the chance to drop any legendary item.